# Logging off from all servers in a domain

Tags: windows, powershell, server

Occasionally I forget to log off from a server or am disconnected through an error and I don't remember the name of the server. And my domain account starts getting periodically locked out, so I have to access logs on DC to find out which server(s) keep locking my account and log off from it/them. So I wanted to write to script in powershell that would log me off from all servers in a domain (with the exception of the server where I run the script on of course) without me needing to search which to log off from. This is what I have:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Silentlycontinue"
$Servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
$ScriptBlock = {
        $Sessions = quser | ?{$_ -match $env:USERNAME}
        if (($Sessions).Count -ge 1)
        {
            $SessionIDs = ($Sessions -split ' +')[2]
            Write-Host "Found $(($SessionIDs).Count) user login(s) on $Server."
            $SessionIDs | ForEach-Object
            {
                Write-Host "Logging off session [$($_)]..."
                logoff $_
            }
        }
}
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    if ($Server -isnot $env:COMPUTERNAME)
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {$ScriptBlock}
                    
    }
}
```

But when I launch the script, nothing happens. The script doesn't return any errors but doesn't log me off from any server, nor does it write any of the messages from Write-Host cmdlet, obviously. I noticed the `$SessionIDs` variable definition only returns ID of the first session. Usually this shouldn't be a problem, since it's unlikely I will have more than one session on a server, but I'd like to have this insurance. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in the script?

Comment: Try a group policy instead. Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limit contains settings for logging off idle sessions.

Comment: in addition to the comment of vonPryz: your account won't be locked out due to "forgotten" rdp sessions, that can't be the root cause. I saw this often when people did map networkdrives by specifying their credentials and then later they did change the password.... furthermore filter at least on the OS currently you receive any computer account available in AD

Comment: Comment/Remove the `$ErrorActionPreference = "Silentlycontinue"` you'll probably see what's wrong ;). I'd quickly suggest use "-ne" instead of "-isnot", do not add embraces around $scriptblock in your invoke-command. And finally, $SessionIDs is not explicitely an array if only one session, so your foreach-object won't work. And I totally agree with @vonPryz suggestion

Comment: GPO is not possible solution. We had that on older domain but it was in times when the environment was. say, "wild". Now it is a lot more controlled and to create GPO is basically impossible because of the amounts of necessary approvals, explanations and business justifications and so on. Also there are situations where you do need to stay logged for, let's say, 12 hours while not at work to run some long task so this would prevent it. Root cause are the disconnected sessions, we can see that in logs on DC, saying "server xyz locked out account abc" and after logging off the account stops

Comment: getting locked out. So there's no doubt about the root cause of it. I'll try to make $Sessions an array implicitly, but I think I already did.

Comment: Removing `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContnue` makes the script run indefinitely, again without any comments or error messages.

Comment: if you want $sessionsIDs to be an array, do it like `$SessionIDs = , ($Sessions -split ' +')[2]`
But technically apart if your login is let's say **synek** and another login is **psynek** (and it's another risk in your script) i don't see how you could technically have multiple rdp (maybe console session? )

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the risk of user name, but we have two accounts - standard account (name.surname) and administrator's account (a.name.surname or adm.name.surname) With the standard account we are unable to log on servers except jump (terminal) servers so that shouldn't pose a problem as it should only log off the admin accounts. We usually log in the jump servers with the admin accounts as well because it's quite inconvenient to replace suggested user name when trying to log in to a server every time. And there are also other disadvantages when using standard account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with objects is much easier if you can just parse the output of `QUser.exe`. Given your scenario, here's my take on it:

```
$servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter '*').Name.Where{$_ -ne $env:COMPUTERNAME}
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    if (-not ($quser = ((QUser.exe /server:$server) -replace '\s{20,39}',',,' -replace '\s{2,}',',' 2>&1) | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ -match $env:USERNAME })) {
        Continue
    }
    Write-Verbose -Message "$($quser.Count) session(s) found on $server." -Verbose
    ($quser.Trim() | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'USERNAME','SESSIONNAME','ID','STATE','IDLE TIME','LOGON TIME').foreach{
        Write-Verbose -Message "Logging user [$($_.UserName)] off." -Verbose
        LogOff.exe $_.ID /server:$server
    }
}
```

Filtering should always happen before hand meaning, filter out your computer name on your first call to `Get-ADComputer`. Since you're using `QUser.exe` and `LogOff.exe` to begin with, I'd recommend the use of it all the way through since `LogOff` accepts an `ID` value that `QUser` outputs.

Next, placing the call to `quser` inside your `if` statement does two things in this case.

1. Filters for all users matching `$ENV:UserName`
2. Returns `$true` if anything is found, and `$false` if not found.

   - So, switching the results using `-not` will turn `$false` into `$true` allowing the execution of the code block which will just `continue` to the next server.
   - This in turn doesn't bother with the rest of the code and continues onto the next computer if no matching names were found.

The use of `$quser` inside the `if` statement is so you can save the results to it if more than one name is found; `(..)` allows this as it turns the variable assignment into an expression having the output pass through onto the pipeline where it is either empty, or not.

Finally, referencing the `$quser` variable we can convert the strings into objects piping to `ConvertFrom-Csv`. Only step left to do is iterate through each row and passing it over to `LogOff` to perform the actual logoff.

---

*If you've noticed, the headers are manually-specified because it is filtered out by the `Where-Object` cmdlet. This is a better approach seeing as there could be "more than one" RDP Session, now you're just left with those sessions matching the name which can be saved to `$quser`, so no extra filtering is needed down the line.*

Comment: For some reason when I use this solution I get the announcement about how many connections are on which server (if there are some) but nothing else happens. Meaning I just see
`
VERBOSE: 1 session(s) found on server1.
VERBOSE: 1 session(s) found on server2.
`
And that's all. I honestly don't understand why the second part doesn't work myself.

Comment: You never see `logging user.... Off` message?

Comment: Yes. The activities within the Foreach method are not performed.

Comment: Would recommend halting the script when you get the first message and trying to run `$quser.Trim() | ConvertFrom-Csv ......` (*include headers*) by itself and see if there's anything that is populated.

Comment: This is what I got when I ran one command after another in the blue part of ISE: `Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'Foreach'`

Comment: @PetrSynek, I see. Change `.foreach{` to `| foreach-object {`

Comment: Works, thanks. Unfortunately I found it's reasonably usable on one of our domains only, since on the second it takes over 6 hours to complete due to the amount of servers. And that's after filtering out all end users' laptops and desktops

Comment: @PetrSynek, you can look into threading which should speed it up quite a bit but, would be up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I notice a few things...

*"First, I don't think `quser | Where-Object {$_ -match $env:USERNAME}` will ever return anything. The output of `quser` will not contain the hostname."*

Try this for getting logon sessions:

```
$Sessions = (query user /server:$Env:ComputerName) -split "\n" -replace '\s\s+', ';' | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Next, when you reference the `$Server` variable on the remote machine in your script block, it is out of scope. You would need to use `$Using:Server` in the script block.

Lastly, the `-isnot` operator doesn't compare value, it compares type. So in your last foreach, the if statement evaluates to "if type string is not type string" and will not run. Try `-ne` or `-notlike` instead.

Comment: Good points. Looks like the OP is using `quser` inside a scriptblock to pass onto `Invoke-Command`. You also could just use `... ',' |  ConvertFrom-Csv` to save yourself some typing. The RegEx pattern of `\s\s+` wouldn't work for multiple users either.

Comment: There's `quser | ?{$_ -match $env:USERNAME}` not `$env:COMPUTERNAME`. I'm interested in user's name, not computer's in this line. And yes, I didn't know the exact meaning of `-isnot` which I now corrected.

Comment: Ah, my mistake @Petr. Not sure why I was thinking `$env:COMPUTERNAME`.

Comment: @PetrSynek regarding your answer where you say `Write-Host` is still not giving the server's name... Did you try re-scoping the variable as I mention in this answer? Inside `$ScriptBlock`, try changing `$Server` to `$Using:Server`

Comment: `$Using:Server` worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I modified the script this way and it works, sort of. It logs off account from servers, which is the main goal. There are still some glitches, like the message it sends from the first Write-Host doesn't give server's name, the message from second one gives a different value than it should (it gives [1] value after -split instead of [2] for some reason; but those are not really that important things, even though I will try to make at least the first message right) and `$SessionIDs` still gives only the first value, but usually you shouldn't have more than one RDP session per server. I've seen more sessions of one user, but that is very rare. But I'd also like to fix this if possible. Nevertheless, the script basically does the most important thing. But if someone has a suggestion how to fix the glitches I mentioned I would be grateful.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Silentlycontinue"
$Servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
$ScriptBlock = {
        $Sessions = quser | ?{$_ -match $env:USERNAME}
        if (($Sessions).Count -ge 1)
        {
            $SessionIDs = , ($Sessions -split ' +')[2]
            Write-Host "Found $(($SessionIDs).Count) user login(s) on $Server."
            Foreach ($SessionID in $SessionIDs)
            {
                Write-Host "Logging off session $SessionID..."
                logoff $SessionID
            }
        }
}
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    if ($Server -ne $env:COMPUTERNAME)
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
    }
}
```